# Expanding a variable within Double Quotes in Java

Tags: java, shell, variables, jdbc, command-line-arguments

I have a Java Application program that runs various Unix commands while the main application is executing.

```
public static void shellExec(){
    try{

       System.out.println("Entering into the test shell loop");
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
        commands.add("filePath"); //(filepath is the location of a file which contains various Unix command)
         System.out.println(commands);


        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
         pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();
        System.out.println("Started the Process Builder");


        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null, previous = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            if (!line.equals(previous)) {
                previous = line;
                out.append(line).append('\n');
                System.out.println(line);
            }


    }catch(Exception ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);

    }   

public static void main(String args[]) {

ds = new SQLMXDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:t4sqlmx://" + args[0] + ":11600/");
    ds.setUser("super");
    ds.setPassword(args[1]);
    ds.setCatalog("SPM60");
    ds.setSchema("RUV60");
    ds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    ds.setMinPoolSize(5);
    ds.setMaxStatements(10);
    String filePath = args[2]; 

     stmtExample();
}
```

Now as you must have guessed that filePath(to be used in shellExec method) is captured at Run Time,

```
java retest "dev.ind.pascal.com" "passwd" "dev/config/proc.sh"
```

But when i call this filePath in shellExec method:
    commands.add("filePath");
The variable is not expanded and hence the shellExec method fails. Note that the double quote is mandatory. Please tell me how to achieve this. I tried:
    commands.add(\"filePath\")
but it still doesnot work. Please help.

Now the filePath keeps on changing every week, So i cant hardcode that value within the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
command.add("\"" + filepath + "\"");
```

Comment: test11.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
            commands.add("\"" + filePath + "\"");
                                ^
  symbol:   variable filePath 
  location: class test11 .... Some how this value is not getting inside the shellExec method...

Comment: @Smruti you need to pass the variable file path to shellExec() method or else make filePath as static global variable. Then it should work. Or if you could post the full class code i could correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try by removing filepath from quotes. The line will look as follows:

```
commands.add(filePath);
```

When you write `commands.add("filePath")` you are not passing value of variable **filePath**, instead you are passing string of value **filePath**

I set value of filePath to "C:/test/I am here"
and got the following response:

```
Entering into the test shell loop
[C:/test/I am here]
```

Comment: In that way I would miss the double quote which is necessary for commands.add("file location")

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `filePath` a static variable of your class. In your code it is a local variable of your `main` method, and therefore inaccessible to the `shellExec` method. Then remove the quotes from `"filePath"` in your `shellExec` method, so you are passing the static variable and not the `String` `"filePath"`.

```
class MyClass {

  static String filePath;

  public static void shellExec(){
      try{

         System.out.println("Entering into the test shell loop");
          List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
          commands.add(filePath); //(filepath is the location of a file which contains various Unix command)
      ...
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    ds = new SQLMXDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:t4sqlmx://" + args[0] + ":11600/");
    ds.setUser("super");
    ds.setPassword(args[1]);
    ds.setCatalog("SPM60");
    ds.setSchema("RUV60");
    ds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    ds.setMinPoolSize(5);
    ds.setMaxStatements(10);
    filePath = args[2]; 

    stmtExample();
  }

}
```

If you need to preface the `filePath` with a command name, you can do something like this:

```
commands.add("filePath " + filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add single quotes for filepath like,

```
command.add("'filepath'");
```

Comment: filePath value is not getting expanded this way.

Comment: Thank you for giving time on this. Thanks much.